# Please review the code- CSS3 rotation transform the text too

Tags: css

am having trouble with the following code. please help me to fix

code

```
<div class="mosaicflow__item">
  <h3>has been the industry's standar</h3>           
</div>
```

css

```
.mosaicflow__item:hover{
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear 0s;
    background: #faffeb;
   }
```

it is rotating the `<h3>` too. so cant read it after rotate.

thanks

Comment: Well yes, you have a CSS rule that rotates it. If you don't want it to rotate take it out of the div or apply to CSS rule to only the part you want to rotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi vixon YES it rotates the parent and all his childrens. so since h3 is the child it will rotate too

**demo** :http://jsfiddle.net/6FQLX/

**the markup:**

```
<div class="mosaicflow__item">
    <h3>has been the industry's standar</h3>  
</div>
```

**the style:**

```
.mosaicflow__item{
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
       -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
        -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d; 
    -webkit-perspective: 800px;  
     -moz-perspective: 800px;  
      -ms-perspective: 800px; 
       -o-perspective: 800px; 
          perspective: 800px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 1.0s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s linear 0s;
    transition: all 1.0s linear 0s;
    background: #faffeb;
    position:relative;
   }
.mosaicflow__item:hover{
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
   }
```

read more here http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/understanding-3d-transforms/